# Getting values from custom classes within an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I currently have some point objects within an NSMutableArray (called `q`), within a `SiteEvents` class. I'm trying to access the values using the code below and its just returning X: 0.0 Y: 0.0. How can I get the x and y values?

```
    NSLog(@"X: %f Y: %f",[(SitePoint*)[[SiteEvents q] objectAtIndex:i]x],
                         [(SitePoint*)[[SiteEvents q] objectAtIndex:i]y]);
```

**Edit**

The method above worked all along. The error was due to not synthesizing `q`within the `SiteEvents` class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:  I think I may have misunderstood your question.

Assuming you have SiteEvents as your top level object which holds an NSMutableArray of points, this is what you'll need to do:

```
    NSMutableArray* points = [siteEventInstance getPoints]; //if you're exposing the point list via a method.
    float x = [points objectAtIndex: i].x;
```

---

**old response**

If you have an array of SitePoint object, you can access the site point objects by indexing into the array like this:

```
    SitePoint* s = (SitePoint*) [q objectAtIndex:i];
```

Then you need to get to the point object within 's'.  This will differ depending on how you exposed the point object within SitePoint.

```
    float x = s.point.X; //If point is a property or a field do this

    float x = [s getPoint].X; //If the point object is exposed via a method.
```

You can combine all of the above concepts (as you have attempted to do) like this:

```
    float x = ((SitePoint*) [q objectAtIndex:i]).point.X;  //if point is a property or a field

    float x = [((SitePoint*) [q objectAtIndex:i]) getPoint].X; //If the point object is exposed via a method.
```

note: i wrote this without having x-code open ;-)

Comment: 'q' is within a custom object called SiteEvents so I have tried SitePoint* s = (SitePoint*) [[SiteEvents q] objectAtIndex:i]; but when I try calling a method of s it does nothing..

Comment: The old response worked when i replaced q with [SiteEvents q] AND synthesised 'q' within the SiteEvents class... I didn't think you needed to synthesise on Mac, I thought that was just an iOS thing.